# regular expression help for div[3]

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a xpath like `/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/p/a[2]/strong`.

Everytime `div[3]` part changes to `div[4],div[5],div[6]...etc`. I need help on how to deal with those changes.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't help without more context about what the page looks like, it's HTML etc.

Comment: can you please paste your HTML code here..

Comment: The xpath that you have written is called xpath by position and is not advisable to write xpath using position until absolutely required. Contrary to the belief xpath is brittle I have using xpath for more than 3 years now and have not had many failures. It is easy to write once you know how. Please share the html will help you out. Also do not use xpath generated by firepath.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid XPATH as much as you can. Or at lease use shorter XPATHs.
Try to scan your element via FirePath plugin for firefox, it generates more compact paths.